# How to generate a multidimensional cube in Python

Tags: python, numpy

This program creates a cube of size Gridsize**3 with user choice of starting point and space between point (even if they are not function parameters there isn't difficult to implement).

```
import numpy as np

def CreateMap(Gridsize):

    X = Y = Z = Gridsize
    M = np.zeros(shape=(X*Y*Z, 3))

    d_x = 5 / Gridsize  # increment of the cube x dimension
    d_y = 5 / Gridsize
    d_z = 5 / Gridsize

    x0 = -1.0
    y0 = 1.0
    z0 = 0

    x = np.arange(x0, X * d_x, d_x, dtype=float)
    y = np.arange(y0, Y * d_y, d_y, dtype=float)
    z = np.arange(z0, Z * d_z, d_z, dtype=float)

    g = 0
    for i in range(X):
        for j in range(Y):
            for k in range(Z):
                M[g, 0] = x[i]
                M[g, 1] = y[j]
                M[g, 2] = z[k]

                g = g + 1
   print(M)
   return 0
```

I was wondering what was the best method to create an hyper cube of size Gridsize**n were n will also be user defined?

Comment: Isn't the second term in `np.arange` (i.e. `X * d_x`)  always `5`?

Comment: no, it's just a way to define dx.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).  Instead of your `for` loops, you can just do

```
M = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you guys have optimization advice...

```
import numpy as np
def CreateMap(Gridsize, x0, xf):

k = np.shape(x0)[0]
M = np.zeros(shape=(Gridsize**k, k))
d_x = np.zeros(k)

for i in range(k):
    d = 0
    j = 0
    d_x[i] = (xf[i] - x0[i]) / (Gridsize - 1)  # increment of the cube x dimension
    x = np.arange(x0[i], xf[i]+d_x[i], d_x[i], dtype=float)
    for v in range(Gridsize ** (k - i - 1)):
        for j in range(Gridsize):
            temp = x[j]
            for z in range(Gridsize ** i):
                M[d, i] = temp
                d = d + 1
print(M)
return 0

x0 = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
xf = np.array([10, 2, 5])
CreateMap(4, x0, xf)
```